# react route how to import local scss file only apply to one js file?

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-router

In one React app with React Router, for each route component, I would like to have one local scss file only apply to this file.

For below example, about.js imported about.scss, **what I want to have is: about.scss override the global style in app.scss only in about.js. However, it overrode everything in the app**

**app.js - imported app.scss which I prefer as a global style**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./app.scss";  // global scss
import About from "./about";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>question about scss in react route</h1>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <hr />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className={"myMargin"}>home</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**app.scss (the global style)**

```
h3.myMargin {
  margin: 10px
}
```

**about.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./about.scss";

export default function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className={"myMargin"}>About</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**about.scss (I want to be a local style, however, it applied to everywhere in the app)**

```
h3.myMargin {
  margin: 100px
}
```

Any suggestion how to structure my style code?

Comment: You could add another className that's specific to the about component, then scope everything accordingly (e.g. `.about h3.myMargin: { }`). You could use [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).

Comment: ^^ If you're using Create React App, their [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) mentions how to use CSS modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty (and caveat) of CSS is in the first C of its acronym —which stands for  *cascading*— meaning there is a cascade of (fairly predictable) rules to follow.

In this case `about.scss` being imported later, will override your h3 from app no matter what.

### 1) Use a container:

```
import React from "react";
import "./about.scss";

export default function About() {
  return (
    <div className='about-page'>
      <h3 className="myMargin">About</h3> // note: no need for {"myMargin"}
    </div>
  );
}

// about.scss
.about-page {
  h3.myMargin {
    margin: 10px
  }
}
```

### 2) Using CSS Modules:

Another one is to use **CSS Modules**, enabled by default if you use a fairly recent version of `create-react-app`:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./About.module.scss";

export default function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className={styles.myMargin}>About</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

// About.module.scss
.myMargin {
  margin: 10px
}
```

This will generate a unique className, so your processed code will look something like this:

```
<div>
  <h3 class='About_myMargin_mVxOd>About</h3>
</div>
```

The random hash (*mVxOd* as an example) will allow your styles to not overwrite each other.

There are pros and cons of both methods, the biggest problem when using regular CSS/SCSS imports is that you are at the mercy of the rules of CSS: if you accidentally create a global class `.error` then the rules will cascade to any component and its hard to keep track. Importing Bootstrap for example, will overwrite a whole lot of CSS names that you have no idea about (until you realize your CSS is off).

Another problem is that, if a said route doesn't import a CSS file, but later on following a different path of routes does import the file, you could end up with different styling. This has happened to us a few times, so it's a must to be extra careful especially in bigger teams.

CSS Modules has a few big drawbacks, first one being that you cannot directly override a style from another CSS file just by overriding its CSS class (because of said hash). Second, you cannot access nested CSS selectors allowed by SASS.

I personally have used both for production and personal projects and both are equally great -- when used carefully.

There is a third popular option called Styled Components. It's personally not my preferred and I haven't used it much, but you can learn more abouut it on its [official page](https://styled-components.com/). It looks like this:

```
const Title = styled.h3`
  margin: 10px;
`

render() {
  return <Title>About</Title> // creates an h3 tag
}
```

One last one, being CSS in JS which I haven't used enough either.