# React use css from imported files only

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5, sass-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

Hi guys I have an issue with my css in the react project

I have a component called `header.jsx` and the `header.scss` file is imported in it, so I want the css to be applied from `header.scss` only not from any other file (even though the className names are same).

There is a way to wrap around with a div and provide unique className,or use `css-modules` but can the same be done with webpack configuration ? I tried to change a bit but couldn't let it happen.

Below is my webpack config for the project

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "./public/index.html" }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
    filename: "index.bundle.js",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    port: 9000,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /nodeModules/,
        resolve: {
          extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
        },
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60699361/13405106) may help

Comment: already mentioned, i dont wanna wrap it around with div, I just wanna to do with webpack configs if it is possible :)